# Correct way of Creating multiple stores with mobx and injecting it into to a Component - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, state-management

As suggested here in the Mobx [documentation](https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html) I have created multiple stores in the following manner:

```
class bankAccountStore {
  constructor(rootStore){
    this.rootStore = rootStore;
  }
...

class authStore {
  constructor(rootStore){
    this.rootStore = rootStore;
  }
...
```

And finally **creating a root store** in the following manner. Also [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126615/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-single-mobx-store-for-an-app) to construct children stores within master's store constructor. Moreover, I found that sometimes my child store has to observe some data from parent store, so I pass this into child constructors

```
class RootStore {
  constructor() {
    this.bankAccountStore = new bankAccountStore(this);
    this.authStore = new authStore(this);
  }
}
```

**Providing to the App** in following manner:

```
<Provider rootStore={new RootStore()}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

And **injecting to the component** in like this:

```
@inject('rootStore') 
@observer
class User extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //Accessing the individual store with the help of root store
    this.authStore = this.props.rootStore.authStore;
  }
}
```

**Question 1: Is it this the correct and most efficient way to inject the root store into the component every time even if it needs a part of the root store?**

**Question 2: If not, what is the best way to inject the auth store into the user component?**

**EDIT: I have made an answer concluding the github discussion. Link of the discussion provided in the answer**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This answer may be opinionated but it may help the community indirectly.
 After a lot of research, I saw below approaches used in practice by many. General methods Have a root store that can act as a communication channel between stores.

**Question 1: What's the best way to organise stores and inject them into the component?**

**Approach 1:**

> **App.js**

```
// Root Store Declaration
class RootStore {
    constructor() {
      this.userStore = new UserStore(this);
      this.authStore = new AuthStore(this);
    }
}    
const rootStore = new RootStore()

// Provide the store to the children
<Provider 
    rootStore={rootStore}
    userStore={rootStore.userStore}
    authStore={rootStore.authStore}
>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

> **Component.js**

```
// Injecting into the component and using it as shown below
@inject('authStore', 'userStore')
@observer
class User extends React.Component {
    // only this.props.userStore.userVariable
}
```

**Approach 2:**

> **App.js**

```
class RootStore {
    constructor() {
      this.userStore = new UserStore(this);
      this.authStore = new AuthStore(this);
    }
} 
const rootStore = new RootStore()

<Provider rootStore={rootStore}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

> **Component.js**

```
// Injecting into the component and using it as shown below
@inject(stores => ({
    userStore: stores.userStore,
    authStore: stores.authStore,
    })
)
@observer
class User extends React.Component {
    // no this.props.rootStore.userStore,userVariable here, 
    // only this.props.userStore.userVariable
}
```

Approach 1 and Approach 2 doesn't make any difference other than syntax difference. Okay! that is the injection part!

**Question 2: What's the best way to communicate between stores? (Try to avoid it)**

> **Now I know a good design keeps stores independent and
> less coupled. But somehow consider a scenario where I want the
> variable in `UserStore` to change if a certain variable in `AuthStore`
> is changed. Use `Computed`. This approach is common for both the above approaches**
>
> **AuthStore.js**

```
export class AuthStore {    
    constructor(rootStore) {
        this.rootStore = rootStore
        @computed get dependentVariable() {
          return this.rootStore.userStore.changeableUserVariable;                                      
        }
    }
}
```

> I hope this helps the community. For more detailed discussion you can
> refer to the [issue raised by me on
> Github](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1935)

Comment: Since this answer is getting lot of upvotes, please note that these approaches do not work with serializer if you want to use mobx in a SSR project

Comment: Just in case someone looks for React Functional component use of this, i used it in following way -
`import React, { useEffect } from 'react';`
`import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';`

`const UserManagementScreen = ( props ) => {`

`    const { userStore } = props;`
`    // Other State`

`    return (`
`        <>....</>`
`    )`
`}`

`export default inject('userStore')  (observer(UserManagementScreen));`
`

Comment: Both approaches has the disadvantage that each individual store can access a sibling store by accessing the rootstore instance. There should be no reason for that. Everything both store need should be put in the rootstore.

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend you to have multiple stores, to avoid chaining of stores. As we do in our application:

```
class RootStore {
    @observable somePropUsedInOtherStores = 'hello';
}

class AuthStore {
    @observeble user = 'Viktor' ; 

    constructor(rootStore) {
        this.rootStore = rootStore;
    }

    // this will reevaluate based on this.rootStore.somePropUsedInOtherStores cahnge
    @computed get greeting() {
        return `${this.rootStore.somePropUsedInOtherStores} ${this.user}`
    }
}

const rootStore = new RootStore();

const stores = {
    rootStore,
    bankAccountStore: new BankAccountStore(rootStore),
    authStore = new AuthStore(rootStore) 
}

<Provider {...stores}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

In such a manner you can access exactly the store you need, as mostly one store covers one domain instance. Still, both sub-stores are able to communicate to `rootStore`. Set its properties or call methods on it.

*If you do not need a cross store communication - you may not need a `rootStore` at all. Remove it and don't pass to other stores. Just keep 2 siblings stores*

Answering your question on injecting not a whole store, you may benefit from `mapperFunction` (like `mapStateToProps` in redux) [docs here](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#customizing-inject)

```
@inject(stores => ({
        someProp: stores.rootStore.someProp
    })
)
@observer
class User extends React.Component {
// no props.rootStore here, only props.someProp

}
```

Comment: I got everything except the one thing . What's the point of creating empty `rootStore` and then passing it's reference to the other stores?

Comment: Obviously `rootStore` is not empty and contains some functionality. From the best practices of separation of concerns it is better to let `bankAccountStore ` and `authStore` know about `rootStore` (that will allow them to communicate) instead of letting them know about one another. So `rootStore` may play a role of a bus to allow other stores to communicate.

Comment: So the `new rootStore()` is the instance of the same `rootStore` class that is declared in the question. Correct?

Comment: If not can you add the declaration of class `rootStore` in your answer?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: But what if I want to access data into the one store from another store? Because it is not priorly known what data will be shared among stores and after realizing it moving it to the root store is an overhead I guess.

Comment: The main goal I want to point - prefer cross store communication over 3rd store, not direct, as this will allow you to better isolate stores from one another. I don't know the specifics of your app, but this is a development process, you see that something should work in another manner - your refactor. Yes this is overhead - but if your sores are dependent on one another - expect big troubles when you will have to refactor one or remove. When this may not be valid for app with 2 stores, but if you have 20 - this will matter.

Comment: @ShevchenkoViktor How do you handle if you had a component which is being injected with `bankAccountStore` as per your example, and is rendered multiple times. 
And if the parent component needs to access all the values in `bankAccountStore` (which could have multiple bank account details ).

Comment: one of the clean solution

Comment: I like that stores are not chained here. More OOP approach.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing your RootStore directly in api.js file before passing it to Provider is sometimes not what you want.
This can make injecting the instance of main store class harder into other js files:

#### Example 1:

app.js - Creates new instance before passing it to Provider:

```js
//Root Store Declaration
class RootStore {
    constructor() {
      ...
    }
}    

const rootStore = new RootStore()

// Provide the store to the children
<Provider rootStore={rootStore}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

#### Example 2:

RootStore.js - creates new instance directly in RootStore class:

```js
// Root Store Declaration
class RootStore {
    constructor() {
      ...
    }
}    

export default new RootStore();
```

`Example 1` compared to `Example 2`, makes harder to access/inject the store in another part of the application, like in `Api.js` described below.

Api.js file represents axios wrapper (in my case it handles global loading indicator):

```js
import rootStore from '../stores/RootStore'; //right RootStore is simply imported

const axios = require('axios');
const instance = axios.create({
 ...
});

// Loading indicator
instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (request) => {
        rootStore.loadingRequests++;
        return request;
    },
    (error) => {
        rootStore.loadingRequests--; 
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
)
```

And using React Hooks, you can inject the store that way:

```js
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";
const YourComponent = ({yourStore}) => {
      return (
          ...
      )
}

export default inject('yourStore')(observer(YourComponent));
```